# Jenkins "Docker Build and publish" plugin not working

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, docker-machine

I tried to build docker image using Jenkins "Docker Build and Publish" plugin in windows 10 machine.For that i pulled jenkins image from docker. My requirement is, On top that jenkins image i need to create one job[SCM from GIT ->build Maven jar -> with DockerFile, try to build the docker image & push that to dockerhub].

First inside **Jenkins-> Manage Jenkins ->Global tool configuration ->Add docker**
[image]

And later i tried to create jenkins freestyle job. In that i add my GITlab project url & credentials.

In Build section, first i configured Maven
[image]

Second in "Docker build and publish" section,

Repository Name as my dockerhub repository name

DOCKER HOST URI - Docker host address from the command "docker-machine env 'docker-machine-name'"

[image]

[image]

And then i clicked Advanced tab in BUILD section, added docker( the one which i add in Jenkins-> Manage Jenkins ->Global tool configuration ->Add docker)
[image]

Whenever, i run the jenkins job, it pulled the code from GITLab and then maven created the jar successfully. After i tried to build the docker image using Dockerfile.

My DockerFile:

[image]

The jenkins job Error logs are

```
[Sample] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven/bin/mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.example:sample >-------------------------
[INFO] Building sample 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ sample ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Sample/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ sample ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ sample ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Sample/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ sample ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Sample/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ sample ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Sample/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ sample ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar (default-jar) @ sample ---
[INFO] Building jar: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Sample/target/demo.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ sample ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.898 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-24T13:32:52Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Sample] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool/docker/bin/docker build -t karthickas/springboot --file=Dockerfile .
error during connect: Post http://10.5.54.173:2376/v1.29/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=karthickas%2Fspringboot&target=&ulimits=null: EOF
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

while debugging,i tried that docker host uri in browser, i got error "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server."

[image]

Did I miss something. Kindly help me to resolve this

**NOTE**: I tried to build docker image & push that to dockerhub using command prompt. Successfully i can create and push to dockerhub.
[image]